# Проблема с клавишей Fn на ноутбуке

Tags: ноутбук, dell

Windows 11. Прикол в том что я когда нажимаю F2, F1, F3 без FN у меня комп звук уменьшает или увеличивает ну делает что эти клавиши делали раньше только когда в придачу был нажат FN. Перестал работать Alt-F4. Помогите пожалуйста. DELL Latitue 5490

Comment: Похоже на включенный Fn Lock. Попробуйте комбинацию Fn + Esc чтобы выключить. И что этот вопрос так минусуют? Нормальный вопрос, хотя заголовок и мутный.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы мне помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на включенный Fn Lock. Попробуйте комбинацию Fn + Esc чтобы выключить.

Answer (score 0):

В BIOS SETUP есть настройка, как по-умолчанию работают эти клавиши. Есть утилита для Windows, которая позволяет менять подобные настройки из Windows (но потом всё равно нужно перезапускать комп).

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, если порыться в реестре можно тоже какие-то кнопки перенастроить? Но это редко делают потому что достаточно BIOS настройки подкрутить.